# How do you find the area of this trapezoid

Tags: geometry, area

How do you find the area of the trapezoid $KCDL$?

[image]

Comment: Try avoiding pictures, but it's ok.

Comment: HINT $ \dfrac{KL}{CD}= \dfrac{36}{48} ;$ Next use formula you wrote at right top corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P$ be the midpoint of $KL$, and $Q$ be the midpoint of $CD$.

Then by similar triangles:

$$\frac{CQ}{AQ} = \frac{KP}{AP}$$
$$\frac{6}{48} = \frac{KP}{36}$$
$$KP = 4.5, KL = 9$$

Now use the formula for the area of a trapezoid: $$\frac{a+b}{2} \cdot h$$

Comment: Quick question. why do you need to do CQ/AQ=KP/AP? thanks

Comment: Because they are similar, therefore in proportional ratio.